# How do you exclude NA values from Leaflet legend?

Tags: r, plot, r-leaflet

Here's my data: https://paste.kodi.tv/omohuzawec

Updated data output from dput: redacted

I'm trying to replicate the following plot:

[image]

Here's the code I've used to replicate so far, the only thing I can't figure out is how to remove the NA from the legend.

```
pal <- colorFactor(palette =  c("#F5DCA4","#E8A46A","#D16769","#B74146"), 
                domain = zipcodes@data$risk.factor)

leaflet(zipcodes) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(
    fillColor = ~pal(risk.factor),
    weight = 1, #weight of lines between zip codes
    color = "gray", #color of line between zip codes
    fillOpacity = .9, #fill opacity of zip codes
    popup = state_popup) %>%
  addLegend("bottomright", 
            pal = pal, #pal = palette declared earlier
            values = ~risk.factor, 
            title= "Risk: Lowest to Highest",
            opacity = 1)
```

[image]

Correct code, it's the na.color that we needed :

```
colorFactor(palette =  c("#F5DCA4","#E8A46A","#D16769","#B74146"), 
                domain = zipcodes@data$risk.factor,
                na.color = NA)
```

Comment: Can you please share your data by providing the output of `dput(zipcodes)` ? The link you provided has information for `risk.factor` but not for latitude and longitude, so we are not able to reproduce the map.

Comment: @canovasjm data is updated in original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do na.color = NA

```
colorFactor(palette =  c("#F5DCA4","#E8A46A","#D16769","#B74146"), 
            domain = zipcodes@data$risk.factor,
            na.color = NA)
```

Comment: FYI, this solution seems to completely remove any polygons with value NA from the map. So, yes, no more NA block in the legend, but also no hover label or color at all for the NA polygons.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who doesn't want NA to appear in their legend, but still wants their polygons with NA values to have hover labels and some sort of color, I also found the [GitHub solution](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/615#issuecomment-656035992) that @canovasjm mentioned, which defines two different palettes, helpful:

```r
pal <- colorFactor(
    palette =  c("#F5DCA4","#E8A46A","#D16769","#B74146"), 
    domain = zipcodes@data$risk.factor,
    na.color = "grey" # desired color for NA polygons on map
)

pal_noNA <- colorFactor(
    palette =  c("#F5DCA4","#E8A46A","#D16769","#B74146"), 
    domain = zipcodes@data$risk.factor
    na.color = NA
)

leaflet(zipcodes) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(
    fillColor = ~pal(risk.factor),
    weight = 1, #weight of lines between zip codes
    color = "gray", #color of line between zip codes
    fillOpacity = .9, #fill opacity of zip codes
    popup = state_popup) %>%
  addLegend("bottomright", 
            pal = pal_noNA,
            values = ~risk.factor, 
            title= "Risk: Lowest to Highest",
            opacity = 1)
```

Comment: This worked for exactly what I was trying to do, perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The function `addLegend()` has an argument `na.label` which by default is set to `"NA"`.  From [here](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/615#issuecomment-656035992) it seems one can set `na.label = ""` to remove the NA label from the legend.

Comment: Ah unfortunately not, I experimented with that first. It removes the text from the label but then there's just a phantom gray box floating at bottom with no text next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe include a CSS with the following rule:

```
.legend i {
  display: none;
}
```

This will make the grey box go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just exclude NA values from the `values` parameter within the add legend function. This allows you to utilize a single palette for the map and legend.

NA is visualized on the map, but not labeled within the legend.

I had the issue with `colorNumeric` where the NA label was displaying off to the side, which is super ugly. :(
[image]

Here is an reproducible example and using `colorFactor`

```r
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

demo(nc, ask = FALSE, echo = FALSE)

# Add arbitrary factor column
nc <- nc |>
  mutate(
    factor_col = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", NA),20)
  )


factpal <- colorFactor(topo.colors(4), nc$factor_col, na.color = "#000000")

leaflet(nc) |>
  addPolygons(color = ~factpal(factor_col))|>
  addLegend(pal = factpal,
            values = nc$factor_col[!is.na(nc$factor_col)])
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Add `na.color=rgb(0,0,0,0)` to the `colorFactor` function along with `na.label = ""` to the `addLegend` function